# addSubview strange effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation

i have animated open NSViewController, which try to add subview:

```
[self.view addSubview:joinToCompanyView];

joinToCompanyView.frame = NSMakeRect(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - joinToCompanyView.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - joinToCompanyView.frame.size.height / 2, joinToCompanyView.frame.size.width, joinToCompanyView.frame.size.height);
```

After i add this subview, i have strange blur effect just for that subview:
[image]

any ideas will be approtiate

Answer (score 2):

Your subView is blurry because the frame is using floating numbers.

To force integers value for your frame just do :

```
[joinToCompanyView setFrame:CGRectIntegral(joinToCompanyView.frame)];
```

You could also cast all your values composing your frame to `int`, but `CGRectIntegral` does all the job for you.

Comment: for macos a solution little bit complicated     CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(viewToOpen.frame.origin.x, viewToOpen.frame.origin.y, viewToOpen.frame.size.width, viewToOpen.frame.size.height);
    CGRect updatedRect = CGRectIntegral(newRect);
    
    [viewToOpen setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(updatedRect)];

Comment: yes, but you get the idea right. When you set the frame as floating point numbers, while rendering this on screen there is blurriness. Since the rendering might not be that precise in pixels. This is taken care when the frame coordinates are rounded off....